# Searching for a javascript function definition within a string using PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, zend-view

I'm using Zend_View_Helper_HeadScript to display javascript function definitions in the head of my webpages, and I extended it to get the javascript code from file if desired.  What I'd like to know is if there would be an easy way to search the headScript output (basically, a series of xhtml script elements) for a javascript function definition, assuming I got and outputted the contents of javascript files (rather than including the srcs.)  I mean, I could search for "function" followed by some function name characters and then "(" but that doesn't account for possible comments in the code.  Is there a quickie function for this that is built into PHP that can search for a javascript function definition? Or something else prebuilt?

Sample output:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// function testMe() {}

function otherTest() {alert('Just testing!');}

/*

function testMe() {}

*/

</script>
```

Obviously testMe() hasn't really been defined here...

For clarity, I'm trying to do something like this:

```
<?php

$htmlScriptElements = $view->headScript()->toString();
$functionName = 'testMe';

$file = '/path/to/testMe.js';
$type = 'text/javascript';
$attrs = array();
$getScript = TRUE;

if (!js_function_definition_found($functionName, $htmlScriptElements)) {

    $view->headScript()->appendFile($file, $type, $attrs, $getScript);

}
```

The headScript helper is home-brew; if $getScript is true, I use file_get_contents() to get the js content and append that instead of including a js file using a url/src.  I realize that it won't find definitions in included js files; I'm fine with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to make a guess here and say what you are wanting is a PHP based [Parser/Lexer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) for Javascript. You may want to take a look at the [Spidermonkey PECL extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/spidermonkey) as it may get you part way there.

Comment: SpiderMonkey might be a bit overkill in this case, but +1 for going in the complete opposite direction of regex

Answer (score 0):

You can test for the existence of a JavaScript function from JavaScript itself with the `typeof` operator, e.g.

```
typeof alert === 'function' // true
typeof foo   === 'function' // false
```

or, if you are not interested in the type, you can do

```
if (window.alert) { ... }
```

where `window` is the scope of the function you are looking for, e.g. `document.getElementById` or `myModule.someFn`

So you don't have to check from PHP. If you would want to do this from PHP, you could iterate over the [*headscript placeholder*](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_View/Helper/Zend_View_Helper_HeadScript.html) and parse the strings inside. I am not aware of a function that would do `findAllJavaScripts()`, so it would require some clever Regex.

Comment: Well, I want to check the code on the server side of things, so that I'm not sending the same function definitions to the client multiple times.

Comment: As far as I know, the headscript helpers prevent duplicates on their own. See http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/163-Using-Zend_View-Placeholders-to-Your-Advantage.html